# I deleted a transaction after:The Transaction is only available on your local machine

Tags: transaction-fees

I waiting for confirmations from a transaction from another person. The issue it that it's only 3 sat/vb.

On my electrum wallet I got the following:

> "The Transaction is only available on your local machine.The currently
> connected server does not know about it.You can either Broadcast it
> now or simply remove it."

What I did is that I deleted it. Will I still received the bitcoins? or it's over for me?

Answer (score 1):

> **I waiting for confirmations from a transaction from another person.**

If the transaction is **"from another person"** that normally means they are sending money and you are the recipient. **They** create the transaction not you.

> **"The Transaction is only available on your local machine."**

That message only appears if **you** create a transaction.

> **I deleted it. Will I still received the bitcoins?**

You, as a recipient, cannot delete transactions created by someone else.

You deleting a transaction you created cannot affect a different transaction which someone else created to send you money.

The sort of confusion apparent in this question makes me suspect that you might be new to Bitcoin and might be being tricked by a criminal, a confidence trickster.

Comment: Yes sir i am new.

Comment: Guess i was tricked. Oh well. It's how it is